# How to deduce the behaviour of $f$ using the relation $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{e^{a|x|^{b}}}=0$ for all $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{e^{a|x|^{b}}}=0 \quad\mbox{for all } a>0.$$

I am trying to understand if from the above relation we can deduce that
$$f(x)> g(x),$$
with $g(x)\sim |x|^q$ for some suitable positive $q$.

From the relation above we can say that for $\varepsilon>0$ it is
$$|f(x)|\le \varepsilon e^{a|x|^{b}} +c_{\varepsilon} \quad\forall t$$
but I don't know how to proceed from that.

Could someone please help me with that?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can deduce that from the limit alone, you would need more information. $f(x)=1/(x^2+n^2)$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit tells you that, precisely, for arbitrary small $\epsilon $, there exists $M>0$ such that for all $|x|>M$, $-\epsilon \,e^{a|x|^b}<|f(x)| < \epsilon \,e^{a|x|^b}$. You definitely cannot deduce the statement that $|f(x)|>C|x|^p $ for all large enough $|x|$ and for some $C>0$.For example, take $f(x)=1$.

Comment: I could be missing something but any power function is negligible compared to $h$. You could take a logarithm instead..

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction. I edited my answer.